How do you show the status bar in a kivy ios app?
I have made a kivy app and have been testing it on iOS with the xcode simulators. How can I force the status bar at the top of the screen (time, battery, etc) to show? I have tried setting Window.fullscreen to False, but that doesn't do anything. I have seen some complicated outdated solutions online but none of them seem to work.

In Sources/main.m, change putenv("IOS_IS_WINDOWED=False") to putenv("IOS_IS_WINDOWED=True").
Additionally, keep an eye on usage of kivy.core.Window. I had set the size of the window for testing in my IDE, and this was causing the app to remain in fullscreen when run on ios, causing the status bar to be hidden.
